# Inserting a variable in sql through laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to insert data into sql in laravel 5
My Code:

```
$a1=Input::get('username');

$a2=Input::get('reg_no');

DB::insert("INSERT INTO ngosignup VALUES($a1,$a2)");
```

But I am getting SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '@gmial.com,a,a,a,a,9,a,9814937684,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N'
>   at line 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO
>   ngosignup(name,email,pass,confirmpass,address,city,pin,state,mobile,registration,secretary,dest,firstmember,mobile1,secondmember,mobile2,thirdmember,mobile3,objective,dev1,place1,obj1,dev2,place2,obj2,dev3,place3,obj3)
>   VALUES(a,amit@gmial.com,a,a,a,a,9,a,9814937684,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL))

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Can you please give more detail ? What is your error ? Why you don't use Eloquent ORM ?

Comment: I am getting the form data in variables a1 and a2 and trying to insert them in database but getting the SQL Syntax error at insert line.@DarkCyber

Comment: yes, then please edit your question and add full SQL Syntax error, just copy and paste it :D, so we can help to check it :D.

Comment: Please add the full Controller code and your ngosignup table structure.

Comment: There was a syntax error,it worked now.Thank you @DarkCyber

Answer (score 0):

Try Eloquent way.. for example of using your db.. Make a Model for ngosignup table and include it on controller

```
public function create(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

        $input = $this->request->all();

        $a1 = $input['username'];

        $a2 = $input['reg_no'];


        $newngo = new ngosignup; //Replace ngosignup with your Model name.

        $newngo->name = $a1;     //name and reg_no should be column name

        $newngo->reg_no = $a2;

        $newngo->save();        //this will add these values into your DB
}
```

You can do this way.. Easier and Flexible.. You can add validator.. Refer to Laravel docs on their official site :)

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\ngosignup;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ngosignupController extends Controller
{

```
public function index() {

$ngo = ngosignup::first(); // this shows first row of table..you              can use get() instead of first to get all table as collection.

$data= array(
    'ngo ' => $ngo
);

  return View('index', $data);
}
```

Then on Index.Blade.php File.. you can display data from ngosignup table like

{{ $ngo->email }}               // replace email with which data to display. if ollection.. use foreach loop to display all data.

Refer to Laravel docs.. they list all methods available..

Comment: Thanks and How we can access database in .blade.php file.I am trying to do that like in Controllers but id didnt worked.Please help @SamSolomon